# How to get end point and see the data in etcd eks cluster

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

''
How to get access the etcd to see and I need to get the endpoint of etcd to configure for calico cni. Please help me to fix this issue.Thanks.
''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but isn't possible to access etcd on EKS clusters, AWS just doesn't allow this because the control plane management is made by them:

> Managed control plane:
> Amazon EKS provides a scalable and highly-available Kubernetes control plane that runs across multiple AWS availability zones. Amazon EKS automatically manages the availability and scalability of the Kubernetes API servers and etcd persistence layer for each cluster. Amazon EKS runs the Kubernetes control plane across three Availability Zones in order to ensure high availability, and it automatically detects and replaces unhealthy control plane nodes.

Comment: I could not able to see  etcd afer using kubectl get svc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to find services:

```
kubectl get svc
```

You will find the *external IP address* and *port* of etcd, for instance you find:
[image]

and can call the endpoint like this `curl http://35.204.136.231:2379/version`